# At each time keep only one section visible in my table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am experimenting with [this](http://ng-table.com/#/demo/4-1) table created with Angular.

As you can see it has each element divided into separate groups that you can toggle on or off.

What I want to achieve is have only one group visible at all times, so when I toggle a group, the open one will close leaving only that selected group visible.

I am not sure how to iterate over all remaining groups and set the *hide* variable to true though.

How can this be done?

Comment: Make a plunker with your code. I'm pretty sure this is as simple as having an appropriate `ng-show` in the `ng-repeat` of the table.

Comment: I did not create anything because a running example is provided at the link. Not to mention that I do not know how to include the ng-tables module in plunker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a methods that hide the other rows and expand only the clicked

```
$scope.switchGroup = function(group, groups){
if(group.$hideRows){
  angular.forEach(groups, function(g){
    if(g !== group){
      g.$hideRows = true;
    }
  });
}

group.$hideRows = !group.$hideRows;
};
```

Its explained here [ng-Table Grouping: Open only row at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841622/ng-table-grouping-open-only-row-at-a-time)

You can check this Plunker I have modified http://plnkr.co/edit/KVrOM7SEVReSYvlJFzva?p=preview

Comment: This seems to be it. But there is a problem with the way it loads. If we only want one group to be visible, then when the page loads it should not start with all of the groups visible, but probably only the first one.
Plunker did not work for me as it displayed the variable names and not the table with the groups, so I had to test it localy, I hope that did not mess with it in some way.

Comment: I meant invisible not visible, sorry.

Comment: @dearn44 I have added a plunker , could you check that this is what you are looking for

Comment: yes that is exactly what I was going for. I was just suggesting that it might be more aesthetically pleasing, or easier for the user if we started with the first group visible, as supposed to having all of the invisible from the start as we do now.

Comment: Hmm , if you what that then you have to set the group.$hideRows for the first index as false

Comment: I tried groups[0].$hideRows = false, the thing is that the variable groups is not created until it is too late. And I am not aware of any "if first item then" control inside ng-repeat.

Comment: try '<tbody ng-init="$groups[0].$hideRows = false" ng-repeat="group in $groups "  sortable="'sortletter'" ng-controller="groupCtrl">'

Comment: do you mind adding this to your question. I think it could be useful for anyone that might check this question on the future.